# PHP array_merge() function

Tags: php, arrays

I have some problems during working with `arrays` using `array_merge function`. Here an example:

**First example:**

```
 $first = array('01' => 1, '03' => 73);
 $second = array('14'=>11, '15' => 23);
 var_dump(array_merge($first, $second));
```

Result is:

```
array(4) { ["01"]=> int(1) ["03"]=> int(73) [0]=> int(11) [1]=> int(23) }
```

Expected:

```
array(4) { ["01"]=> int(1) ["03"]=> int(73) [14]=> int(11) [15]=> int(23) }
```

**Second example:**

```
 $first = array('01'=>3, '03'=>10);
 $second = array('05'=>44, '07'=>3);
 var_dump(array_merge($first,$second));
```

Result is(as expected):

```
array(4) { ["01"]=> int(3) ["03"]=> int(10) ["05"]=> int(44) ["07"]=> int(3) }
```

**Third example:**

```
var_dump(array_merge(array("somekey"=> array("some value"))));
```

Result is(as expected):

```
array(1) { ["somekey"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "some value" } }
```

**Fourth example:**

```
var_dump(array_merge(array("34"=> array("some value"))));
```

Result is:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "some value" } }
```

Expected:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["34"]=> string(10) "some value" } } 

var_dump(array_merge(array("34"=> array("some value"))));
```

As you can see from `third` and `fourth` examples I set string for keys but the result was not as expected.

What is wrong or incorrect of understanding?
Thanks for helping.

**Edited.** Why (example first and second) the result is different, but the keys are string and consist of only with digest?

Comment: seems like a bug to me php is treating '14' as on integer and therefor renumbering the keys :(

Comment: @Exlord - documented behaviour: `Values in the input array with __numeric keys__ will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.` (my emphasis) The leading zero of the keys in $first mean it is treated as a string; though you could make an argument that means it should be treated as an octal number

Comment: @MarkBaker so there is no difference between "14" and 14 ? in my opinion "14" should be considered a string and not a numeric value.

Comment: @Exford `"14"` is a numeric value... you may disagree that it should work this way, but it's still doing exactly what the documentation says it does

Comment: From your words, no difference between "14" and 14?

Comment: Both `"14"` and `14` are numeric __values__ irrespective of datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the manual:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.
>
> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with
>   incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

Keys with a leading zero are being treated as strings, while numeric keys without a leading zero are being treated as numeric

If you want to retain the keys exactly as they are:

```
$first = array('01' => 1, '03' => 73);
$second = array('14'=>11, '15' => 23);
var_dump(
    array_combine(
        array_merge(
            array_keys($first), array_keys($second)
        ),
        array_merge(
            $first, $second
        )
    )
);
```

as long as keys are unique between $first and $second

Answer (score 0):

Definition : Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.

If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

INPUT

```
 <?php
    $array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
    $array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
    $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
    print_r($result);
    ?>
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
[color] => green
[0] => 2
[1] => 4
[2] => a
[3] => b
[shape] => trapezoid
[4] => 4
)
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score -3):

Try **array_merge()** like below:-

```
$first = array('01' => 1, '03' => 73);
$second = array('14'=>11, '15' => 23);
$output = array_merge($first, $second);
print_r($output);
```

**EDIT:-**

```
$first = array('01' => 1, '03' => 73);
$second = array('14'=>11, '15' => 23);
$output = $first + $second;
print_r($output);
```

Comment: You must have misread the question, this is exactly what the OP did

Comment: Thanks all for negative vote of my answer. My understanding on array_merge() was wrong. Now I'm editing my answer which will solve op's problem.

Comment: It give the result, but I trying to resolve problem with array_merge